# Is it possible to find methods during runtime passing a variable or a string name in Kotlin like in groovy

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

For example there is the possibility in groovy to execute a method using following code:

```
    @Test
    void shouldAccessMethodDynamically() {
       DynamicClass dynamic = new DynamicClass()
       String name = 'dynamicMethod'

       assert dynamic."$name"() == "dynamic"
       assert dynamic."dynamicMethod"() == "dynamic"
    }
```

Is this also possible in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a method by name using regular java reflection API:

```
val dynamic = DynamicClass()
val name = "dynamicMethod"

dynamic.javaClass.getMethod(name).invoke(dynamic)
```

If you like to do it in more "kotlin way", you can use it like:

```
DynamicClass::class.memberFunctions.find { it.name == "name" }?.call(dynamic)
```